# Create an appointment in outlook with a category in powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm trying to create an appointment on outlook with a powershell script but I can't find how to define the categories for the appointment. I've googled a bit and what I tried failed: e.g. `$meeting.Categories.Add("CATEGORY NAME")`.

```
$ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$meeting = $ol.CreateItem('olAppointmentItem')
$meeting.Subject = 'SOME TEXT'
$meeting.Body = 'SOME TEXT'
$meeting.Location = 'Virtual'
$meeting.ReminderSet = $true
$meeting.Importance = 1
$meeting.MeetingStatus = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMeetingStatus]::olMeeting
$meeting.Recipients.Add('EMAIL')
$meeting.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
$meeting.Start = Get-Date -Date "2021-10-18T16:20:33Z"
$meeting.Duration = 60

# Don't know how to set category

$meeting.Send()
```

Can anybody help with the syntax for the categories?

Answer (score 1):

Just found it... If the category is called "CATEGORY TEXT":

`$meeting.Categories = "CATEGORY TEXT"`

Not sure how it works for more than one category, but I'm not currently looking for that.

Comment: Multiple categories are separated by ",".